# Java regex for sql

Tags: java, sql, regex

For the create table statement below, I would like to parse the trailing metadata, for example, DISTSTYLE and SORTKEY keys.  I couldn't figure the correct regex to identify such strings.

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    id         guid NOT NULL        ,
    name       varchar(25) NOT NULL ,
    address_id guid NOT NULL
)
    DISTSTYLE ALL
    SORTKEY ( d_datekey );
```

I have something like `"\\)\\s+[(DISTSTYLE)(SORTKEY)]+\\s+"` and it is obviously wrong.  Please help.

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? I don't see any pattern here, you want to extract two *specific* strings.

Comment: Please provide sample input and, based on that input, the expected output.

Comment: [java]? could you explain it better?

Comment: I apologize for being slopping in posting this question.  But Hitham provided what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE customer ( id         guid NOT NULL        , name       varchar(25) NOT NULL , address_id guid NOT NULL ) DISTSTYLE ALL SORTKEY ( d_datekey );
```

For this string capture what you need with `.*DISTSTYLE (.*).*SORTKEY \((.*)\).*` it will be in the matched groups

[image]